# CSS - position: absolute; Error

Tags: css, position, absolute

I am using this piece of code in order to have a "Sale" ribbon on top of an image. The problem is, every time I refresh the page the ribbon appears, as it should, however, after half a second the ribbon disappears, no where to be found.

Here is my code:

```
width: 85px;
height: 88px;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: -3px;
right: -3px;
```

Is it the position that is the problem? Or could it be something else?

Comment: It's not a problem with the code you gave. We'd need more information to find the actual source

Comment: Probably something else. Your code, pasted into a JSFiddle or JSBin example, works as expected. If I were you, I'd open my page in a browser, pull up the developer tools, and see what CSS may be applied on top of what you've posted here.

Comment: Do you have the page where this occurs? or recreate it in a fiddle or show us the relative html and css and js. It sounds like some script is doing something with the container position or the actual item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your div with id="wrap" has a z-index of 9999 while the ribbon has a z-index of 1.